# How to move database and attach it to SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, mdf, m, ldf

I am not able to attach a database to a SQL Server 2008 on different machine. I moved the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files after detaching the database from one computer to another. When I try to attach the database on new machine the database does not show up on the file location.

If I browse manually I can see the files (`.mdf` and `.ldf`). There are no hidden files under the `MSSQL > DATA` folder which contains all the other database files.

Also is there a way to backup the database, move it to new machine and add under SQL Server? If yes then how can I do so? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, backup & restore would be much easier - and there is ***TONS*** of **freely available**, excellent documentation on all of this - e.g. [Backup Overview (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx) - please do go read it yourself - it's there, just go read it!

Answer (score 2):

If you see the MDF and LDF files via file explorer, but not in SQL Server Management Studio, your SQL Server Management Studio login might have insufficient permissions

If the SQL Server version is the same for both original and destination instance, there should be no problems to attach the MDF and LDF files

1. Right-click the **Databases** node in **Object Explorer**
2. Select **Attach...**

[image]

3.Click **Add**

[image]

4.Navigate to the folder the MDF and LDF files are stored. make sure the SSMS login has enough privileges for the files/folders

[image]

5.Select the MDF file and click **OK**

The patch for the LDF file will be automatically added if it's in the same folder. If not, add it manually, the same way you added the MDF file

To backup and restore the backup into a new database, see these articles:

[Create a Full Database Backup (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

[Restore a Database Backup (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Milena. I am having the exact same issue. I can see the file in the explorer but cannot see it when I try to attach a database. Also I see the other databases that are present there in SQL server, they point to the same location where I moved the database but I cannot see them in the file explorer. This is really confusing me. 

My same account works fine on a different server and I dont have any issues attaching a database.

Comment: Can you use Windows authentication on SQL Server?

Comment: Hey Milena, I figured it out. I feel so stupid at this point, I was connecting to a different server. Its all good, I was able to attach the database. Thanks again for all your help :)